# How to add a SQL constraint for values in multiples tables

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I am using MySQL.

I have following tables

```
User(UserID, UserTypeID, AccountID)
Account(AccountID, AccountTypeID)
Permission(PermissionID)
UserType(UserTypeID)
AccountType(AccountTypeID)
UserPermission(UserID, PermissionID)
PermissionRule(UserTypeID, AccountTypeID, PermissionID)
```

Is it possible to restrict the following with SQL constraints ?
When a permission is inserted into `UserPermission` table, the `UserTypeID` for that user, the `AccountTypeID` from the account of that user and the `PermissionID` being inserted should be present in the `PermissionRule` table.

Feels like this is probably more for a business rule or a procedure/trigger, but wondering if there is any way to restrict using SQL constraints that I am not aware of.

I am using Spring Data with Hibernate. So any spring or hibernate annotations based restrictions are also useful.

Comment: Primary/foreign key constraints would partially get you the behavior you want.  Could you handle this logic from the application layer?

Comment: I could definitely do this in application layer. But wondering if there is anyway we could do from SQL. Especially, there may be cases when I remove a row in PermissionRule, I like applicable entry to be removed from UserPermission. I guess I may have to write procedure or trigger for such cases...

Answer (score 2):

If it had been Oracle, the answer would be to use "[Check Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#i1002719)".

MySQL [doesn't support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) check constraints.

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines. See Section 1.8.2.3, “Foreign Key Differences”.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want your constraint to behave you probably can do it with Foreign Key Constraints, with the possible help of a Materialized View.

I assume for now, that what yo want is: the 3-tuple of (`UserTypeID, AccountTypeID, PermissionID)` shall be present in the `PermissionRule` table. All the fields are present in the `UserPermission`

If the 3-tuple is unique in `PermissionRule` you can just create a foreign key constraint. If not you  can create a Materialized view based on `SELECT DISTINCT UserTypeID, AccountTypeID, PermissionID FROM PermissionRule` and reference that table from the unique constraint.

If the 3 fields to be constraint aren't present in the `UserPermission` but must be looked up from other tables you can create a Materialized View to perform the necessary joins and put the Foreign Key on that.

MySQL doesn't really support Materialized Views, but you can create them manually using Triggers and normal tables.

As described in this article: http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views